# React add data attribute to each render() with component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To make e2e testing easier I would like to add to each `react` component `data-component=` attribute with component name. I would like to have it done "automatically" (without adjusting `render()` functions everywhere).

Anyone knows how to do it reliably for both class and function based components?

Comment: It's difficult to give a clear answer without seeing any code. A couple of ideas pop up in my head. First off, to add attributes like that programatically you would need some event to happen like onChange or whatever and then do something like (event) => event.target.setNamedItem('data-component'), event.target.getNamedItem(''data-component').value = event.target.id (or whatever data is available).

A little more info about your problem would be helpful :)

Comment: @MstrQKN I need this to be reliable, so need to be on first render and not async events. I simply want to have easy searching via `document.querySelector` for react components to aid in writing e2e tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Component name is set via static property `displayName` for each component. You need to set it manually.
2. Create hoc (higher order component), to wrap component with `div` (or any other html tag) which will have required attribute.

   ```
   const withComponentName(WrappedComponent) => { 
     const displayName = WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'UnnamedComponent';
     return props => (
       <div data-component={displayName}><WrappedComponent {...props} /><div>
     )
   }
   ```
3. Wrap all component export statements with created hoc.

   `export default withComponentName(YourShinyComponent)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use this Webpack plugin to do it for you:

https://github.com/lemonmade/babel-plugin-react-component-data-attribute

**If you're using create-react-app:**

If you've **ejected** already then **just follow the docs** on the plugin's page ☝️

However, if you **have not ejected** already, then you can use either of these solutions to customize your build for a create-react-app project:

- https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra
- https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/